# GCP: List grantable roles per resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am going thru a Qwicklabs tutorial on GCP IAM.

At some point, it mentions that

> Use the gcloud iam list-grantable-roles command to return a list of
>   all roles that can be applied to a given resource.

However the example cited lists the grantable roles by going throughout the entire project:

```
gcloud iam list-grantable-roles //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID
```

Is there a way to run the above command but only on a specific resource, say `Stackdriver` or `BigQuery` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to run the above command but only on a specific
>   resource, say Stackdriver or BigQuery ?

Yes. From the following examples, you should notice a naming pattern.

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names) is Google's document on resource naming.

If you want to go deeper than the project then you must specify an actual resource. You cannot just specify BigQuery, you must specify the dataset in BigQuery. For Stackdriver you must specify an actual log name.

For some resources, gcloud provides the command-line option `--uri`. This will display the resource name:

```
gcloud compute instances list --uri
```

Note: The command line option `--uri` is not supported for all commands. Neither logging nor Biquery support `--uri`.

**Compute Engine:**

```
gcloud iam list-grantable-roles //compute.googleapis.com/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/[ZONE]/instances/[VM_NAME]
```

**BigQuery:**

```
gcloud iam list-grantable-roles //bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/datasets/[DATASET_ID]
```

**Stackdriver Logging:**

```
gcloud iam list-grantable-roles //logging.googleapis.com/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/cloudbuild
```